# Can you bind a keyboard shortcut to line wrapping in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, editor

Simple question. In Xcode's preferences, there's an option to enable line wrapping.  However, I only see that in the preferences dialog, not the menus, so I'm not sure how to add a keyboard shortcut to it.  Is there any way to do so? Is there some Xcode object model that you can access it via scripting or similar?  Kinda surprised it's not in the menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Control-Shift-Command-L**

It’s also in the menu: **Editor > Wrap Lines**

I’m running Xcode 13.3.

Comment: Yeah, I think they added it after I posted this. I filed a radar about it.